# Guava ImmutableSortedSetMultimap?

Tags: java, guava, immutability, multimap, sortedset

Google Guava has a `SortedSetMultimap`. Wonderful. Now where is the immutable version? There exists an `ImmutableSetMultimap`. But what about `ImmutableSortedSetMultimap`? (Please don't reply with "Why do you want one?")

Comment: Sir, elaborate some more on the topic. If I recall correctly, the nature of a set somewhat conflicts with ordering?

Comment: You mean, `TreeSet` doesn't exist?

Comment: To answer the question, there indeed doesn't appear to be one, even though it's a perfectly reasonable thing to have. Maybe you should submit a feature request.

Answer (score 9):

It won't actually implement `SortedSetMultimap`, but `ImmutableSetMultimap.Builder` has an `orderValuesBy(Comparator)` method that you can use, which has the effect that the value collections are `ImmutableSortedSet`s.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for this myself and just discovered this: [Multimaps.unmodifiableSortedSetMultimap()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#unmodifiableSortedSetMultimap-com.google.common.collect.SortedSetMultimap-)

Not *exactly* what we're looking for, but good enough in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the supplementary meaning of `Multimap`, you have the indirect approach (I wrote the code in SO, so it might not work, but the idea is there):

```
SortedSetMultimap<K,V> set = ...;
ImmutableMap<K, ImmutableSortedSet<V>> result = ImmutableMap.copyOf(Maps.transform(set.asMap(), new Function<SortedSet<V>, ImmutableSortedSet<V>>() {
  public ImmutableSortedSet<V> apply(SortedSet<V> s) {
    return ImmutableSortedSet.copyOf(s);
  }
});
```

That is: turn your `SortedSetMultimap` into a `Map<K,SortedSet<V>>`, then a `Map<K,ImmutableSortedSet<V>>`, and then an `ImmutableMap`.

And I don't know enough Guava, but since the `ImmutableSetMultimap` is immutable, the ordering of copied set might remain: that would mean there is absolutely no need for a `ImmutableSortedSetMultimap` for navigation/iteration (apart if you require specific method of `SortedSet`).